# Changing the parallel monitor size in Comma

Tags: raku, commaide

Comma shows a nice parallel threads monitor. However there does not seem to be a way of making it show more than 16 seconds. I that something that can be changed via some editable property?

Comment: Another legit option for seeking an answer is info@commaide.com (per the "Missing something in the documentation? Let us know!" line from https://commaide.com/docs). It might be a faster way to get attention from jnthn et al too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an editable property, but:

1. Ctrl + mouse wheel can be used to zoom in and out.
2. Click and drag to move backward and forward in time.

[image: Example of described Comma timeline navigation]